# Why I can't access Jenkins by server_ip:8080?

Tags: jenkins, google-cloud-platform

I tried to install Jenkins on my gcp instance.
This log shows that jenkins service active

```
● jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-07-15 00:17:18 UTC; 51s ago
   Main PID: 4903 (java)
      Tasks: 48 (limit: 2359)
     Memory: 713.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service
             └─4903 /usr/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080
```

This log shows, that port 8080 opened

```
ubuntu@jenkins:~$ netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN   

ubuntu@jenkins:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

But if I tryied to connect server_ip:8080 browser shows me ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

```
ubuntu@jenkins:~$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

```
ubuntu@jenkins:~$  telnet ::1 8080
Trying ::1...
Connected to ::1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

[firewall rules cgp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/131Tj.jpg)

Comment: From within the instance can you connect `telnet localhost 8080`?

Comment: Then your issue is outside the instance. Not sure about GCP, in AWS you need to allow ports in Security groups to be accessible externally. So I suppose there is something similar in GCP as well.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/131Tj.jpg
Here my firewall rules and i opened 8080 port

Comment: Your configuration based on the screenshots look okay. May I know if you are accessing the Jenkins server from your Home or Office Network?

Comment: From my home network

Comment: It is not listening to IP v4 `0.0.0.0:8080`, including  `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Comment: I need to change 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1 in my gcp firewall ?

Comment: It might be possible to connect with: `telnet ::1 8080`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set allow targets to all instances in the network rather specified target tags in the gcp firewall panel

Comment: Good to know that its already working! Your previous configuration should have also worked if the network tag "tag" is also attached to your Jenkins instance.